# Manage changing column names in Power BI Desktop

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I have a csv which containts 35 columns, the problem is that the last 13 columns name will change monthly.

Now when I'm trying to refresh I receive an error like this " name x was not found".

Is it possible to have dynamic changing names in Power BI Desktop?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First I would remove the generated **Change Type** step, as that will include all the column names when the query was generated.

Then I would select the first 22 columns and choose **Unpivot Columns / Unpivot Other Columns** from the Transform ribbon.  That will unpivot your 13 columns into 13 rows, with 2 columns:

- **Attribute** - the former Column heading
- **Value** - the former cell value

That query design should survive changing column names in the future (besides the 1st 22 columns).